# How to modify Dijit templated widget dom structure when it is parsed?

Tags: parsing, dom, widget, dojo

I'm creating a Dijit templated custom widget defined in a Html like this:

```
<div data-dojo-type="widgets/Test">Bla bla bla</div>
```

This is replaced with a template. For purpose of this example, let's say it's a simple div:

```
<div></div>
```

Now I have a problem. I can't seem to find a way to get this "Bla bla bla" (in other words, initial innerHTML) in a widget and I need it.

Any ideas?

Comment: I kinda found the answer. The "postscript" function has two arguments and the second one is the initial node in the state before the widget template rendering. I'm still wondering if there is a better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking to modify the widget's template when the widget is being parsed, you can override your widget's *markupFactory* function. You can do this in your CustomWidget.js file as follows:

```
var CustomWidget = declare('path/to/CustomWidget', [], {
   // Widget code here.
});

CustomWidget.markupFactory = function(props, node, clazz) {

  // Modify the props defined in data-dojo-props.
  // Modify the node that your widget is declared in.

  // Don't forget to actually return the instance of your custom Widget!
  return new clazz(props, node);  
}
```

Comment: Not suitable for my needs. I would like to mimic what some Dijit widgets are already doing - that is reading the initial DOM of the widget and transform it somehow. For example: instead of 'bla bla bla', I would like to put there a generic list of nodes and do something with it later on the widget initialization.

Comment: Ah, I see. If you want to modify the way that your widget gets parsed,  you need to override its _markupFactory_ function. I'll add more explanation in my answer; let me know if it is more suitable for you. I'm also not fully aware why you would want something in there initially just for you to replace it with a different DOM structure. Why not just define the desired DOM structure in your custom widget's template?

Comment: http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/dijit/layout/TabContainer (check out this "Declarative example"). It's an example of how this can be quite useful. Three ContentPanes inside a TabContainer. You cannot hardcode this.

Comment: I guess what I'm missing is what you are referring to as "this" when you say "this can be quite useful". That declarative example is 100% hard coded, so what about it are you trying to access/change? Are you trying to make a custom TabContainer (i.e. is your widget inheriting from dijit/layout/TabContainer)?

Comment: "This" is meant as something generic. I'm about to create a series of custom widgets, but not for single-only purpose, but for many different ones. So I need to know how to do just about anything. I have a special case where I need to take inside divs (like in the example I gave you) and wrap theme in some additional markup and then do something with them. Is this "something" so neccessary for you to know? :)

Comment: Well designing a widget to do "just about anything" is way too generic. It is completely conceivable, however, to create a Widget hierarchy where your base widget provides the generic functionality that all your widgets will need, and then you can slowly design more custom structures as children (which can have their own children, etc). If you want to wrap the initial inner <div>s in more HTML and perform actions with them, then my solution of overriding your widget's _markupFactory_ method should work perfectly.

Comment: If you imagine my example's CustomWidget to be the TabContainer node in the example you provided, then when the _markupFactory_ method is run, the "node" property will be TabContainer div node, and you will have access to all of its children (as you would if you were to interact with this DOM node any other way). @Alex if you don't mind, I plan on updating both your question and my answer to reflect the results of our conversation (there was a good amount of misunderstanding and back and forth). Let me know if there was anything left unclear.

Comment: Nothing was left unclear. Your final answer was exactly what I was looking for, so thank you ;)